# Groovy get edit type of tfs changeset

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, changeset, jenkins-groovy

I need to get tfs changeset files (I have accomplished this) and also whether it was added or deleted using the groovy plugin on jenkins server.

I cannot figure out how to access the item class that holds the method to get the edit type. I have tried the below code and just cannot figure it out.

```
import java.lang.*
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.util.*
import hudson.scm.*
import hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet.LogEntry
import hudson.plugins.tfs.model.ChangeSet
import hudson.plugins.tfs.model.ChangeSet.Item
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import java.io.Serializable
import java.lang.Cloneable
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder


// work with current build
def build = Thread.currentThread()?.executable

// get ChangesSets with all changed items
def changeSet = build.getChangeSet()
def items = changeSet.getItems()
println "Affected Paths"

def affectedFiles = items.collect {
 it.getAffectedPaths()
 }

def action = items.getAction()
println action.getEditType
```

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

According to your description, seems you would like to display the status next to the changeset or files in the changeset that shows **what type of action** it was.

In TFS we called changeType, [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.VersionControlChangeType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/tfvc/changesets/get%20changeset%20changes#Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.VersionControlChangeType).

Instead of using groovy in jenkins. You could also get this through Rest API. How to, take a look at [VSTS Rest API return specific item from Changeset API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149795/vsts-rest-api-return-specific-item-from-changeset-api)

---

You should  a method that returns an [EditType](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/tfs/hudson/plugins/tfs/model/ChangeSet.Item.html). The method is then used by the index.jelly to determine which icon to display.

Take a look at the sample code here:

```
public EditType getEditType() {
            if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {
                return EditType.DELETE;
            }
            if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
                return EditType.ADD;
            }
            return EditType.EDIT;
        }
```

*Source Link: [jenkinsci/tfs-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/blob/master/tfs/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/tfs/model/ChangeSet.java)*

Comment: No I don't need the icon. I just need to know if a file was deleted or added within the changset.

Comment: @NicolePhillips Sorry, I just mean the status,  in TFS we called changeType, take a look at [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.VersionControlChangeType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/tfvc/changesets/get%20changeset%20changes#Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.VersionControlChangeType), not familiar with groovy in jenkinsci. Have you seen the sample of how to call `getEditType()` method in  https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/blob/master/tfs/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/tfs/model/ChangeSet.java .

Comment: @NicolePhillips Besides, you could also get this through Rest API, how to, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149795/vsts-rest-api-return-specific-item-from-changeset-api  See my update answer.