# Get TFS Changset Edit Type using Groovy in Jenkins build step

Tags: groovy, tfs, jenkins-plugins, tfsbuild, jenkins-groovy

I am new to Jenkins and also Groovy. I need to be able to detect if a file checked into Jenkins was either added or deleted.  I, however, cannot seem to construct the class right to return the edit values.

The link to the the Changeset.Item class is [here](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/tfs/index.html?hudson/plugins/tfs/model/class-use/ChangeSet.html)

The code I am trying to use is:

```
import java.lang.*
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*

import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.util.*
import hudson.scm.*
import hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet.LogEntry
import com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.versioncontrol.specs.version.ChangesetVersionSpec
import hudson.model.User
import hudson.plugins.tfs.commands.RemoteChangesetVersionCommand
import hudson.plugins.tfs.model.ChangeSet.Item

import groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

import java.io.Serializable
import java.lang.Cloneable



// work with current build
def build = Thread.currentThread()?.executable

// get ChangesSets with all changed items
def changeSet = build.getChangeSet()
def items = changeSet.getItems()

println "Affected Paths"
def affectedFiles = items.collect {
 it.getAffectedPaths()
 }
println affectedFiles

Item typeItems = items
def kind = typeItems .collect { 
it.getEditType()
}
println kind
```

The error I am getting is:

```
08:49:00 ERROR: Build step failed with exception
08:49:00 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '[Ljava.lang.Object;@11890e4' with class '[Ljava.lang.Object;' to class 'hudson.plugins.tfs.model.ChangeSet$Item' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: hudson.plugins.tfs.model.ChangeSet$Item(hudson.plugins.tfs.model.ChangeSet)
08:49:00    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnSAM(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:403)
08:49:00    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnNumber(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:319)
08:49:00    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:232)
08:49:00    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:603)
08:49:00    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:38)
08:49:00    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:585)
08:49:00    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:623)
08:49:00    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:594)
08:49:00    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript.evaluate(SecureGroovyScript.java:343)
08:49:00    at hudson.plugins.groovy.SystemGroovy.run(SystemGroovy.java:95)
08:49:00    at hudson.plugins.groovy.SystemGroovy.perform(SystemGroovy.java:59)
08:49:00    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
08:49:00    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
08:49:00    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
08:49:00    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
08:49:00    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
08:49:00    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1727)
08:49:00    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
08:49:00    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
08:49:00    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
08:49:00 Build step 'Execute system Groovy script' marked build as failure
```

I am sure this is a really easy fix. I have tried so many different ways and seem to be getting further from the solution.

Comment: Seems duplicate with this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49779462/groovy-get-edit-type-of-tfs-changeset/49798694?noredirect=1#comment86615791_49798694

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems error thrown by this line:

```
Item typeItems = items
```

problem that `items` is an array if `Item`

and you are trying to assign array into `Item` variable

from your comment and from code it seems the variable `changeSet` contains [`hudson.plugins.tfs.model.ChangeLogSet`](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/tfs/hudson/plugins/tfs/model/ChangeLogSet.html) object

please check it with this code:

```
println ( changeSet.getClass() )
```

if yes, then:

```
changeSet.getItems()
```

should return array of [`hudson.plugins.tfs.model.ChangeSet`](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/tfs/hudson/plugins/tfs/model/ChangeSet.html)

and this should work:

```
//collect all ChangeSet.Items into single array
def childItems = items.collectMany { it.getItems() }
childItems.each{
    println " path = ${it.getPath()} kind = ${it.getEditType()}"
}
```

Comment: I get this error: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: hudson.plugins.tfs.model.ChangeSet.getEditType() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Comment: It looks like it worked however it returned this value: kind = hudson.scm.EditType@8cb1b5

Comment: this worked I had to change it.getEditType() to it.getEditType().getName(). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like below

```
  println("  Changeset: ")
  def changeSet = build.getChangeSet()
  def items = changeSet.getItems()
  for(int i = 0 ; i < items.length; i++) {
    gitChangeSet = items[i]
    author = gitChangeSet.getAuthorName()
    comment = gitChangeSet.getComment().replaceAll("\\n", " ")
    rev = gitChangeSet.getRevision()
    paths = gitChangeSet.getPaths()
    println("      " + (i+1) + ". " + comment)
    println("          Commit: " + rev + " by (" + author + ")")
    for(hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSet.Path path : paths) {
      editType = path.getEditType()
      if(editType == hudson.scm.EditType.ADD) {
        println("             +  " + path.getPath())
      } else if(editType == hudson.scm.EditType.DELETE) {
        println("             -  " + path.getPath())
      } else if(editType == hudson.scm.EditType.EDIT) {
        println("             E  " + path.getPath())
      }
    }
```

Credits: https://github.com/frank1rouse/jenkins_build_avoidance/blob/5723d5f7457cf4993def513deed21950eb67d398/build_avoidance.groovy

Comment: That works for GIT I bet however does not work for TFs changesets

Comment: @NicolePhillips, let me check

Comment: Can you run `changeSet.getAffectedFiles()` and loop through them? Each item you can call `getEditType()` and `getPath()`. I don't have a TFS server to test

Comment: @NicolePhillips, did you get a chance to check this out?